# Monogame - SpriteFont build error

Tags: monogame, spritefont

I am quite new to Monogame. When I try importing a .spritefont file using the Monogame Pipeline GUI Tool and then build it, it gives me an error: "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'freetype6.dll'". I tried to go into the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools" directory, and I found out that the dll is there. I am really confused why is this happening.

I am using VS Community 2017 and Monogame 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these 2 methods:

1. - Try downloading then installing Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4. The download link is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679
   - Try downloading then installing Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. The download link is: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784
2. Try re-compiling freetype6 yourself if method 1 doesn't work.